# Cron every day at 2PM & 3PM

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to figure out how to set cron to run every day at 2PM & 3PM. Is this correct?

The reason I'm asking is this is for a production server, so I need to be sure.

```
0 18,19 * * *
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it should be:

```
0 14,15 * * ?
```

This assumes that you want the CRON to run at 2pm and 3pm (14:00 and 15:00) using the time of the actual server which would fire the CRON expression.

Your suggested CRON is for 6pm and 7pm, which would be correct perhaps if you were running in a timezone 4 hours ahead, but targeting 2pm in an earlier timezone.